# How to find the benefactor?

Tags: support, bounty

I did not follow the MSE in the last few weeks, and discovered upon arrival  that somebody has awarded a bounty to one of my answers. Is there any way to know the name of this person? Or could that person leave me a comment somewhere?

Comment: Hmm.. looks like for whatever reason, the benefactor who give you the bounty want to close his account and give away his reputation points before his leave. I receive an unexpected bounty to one of my answer like you an hour ago. This is sort of sad :-(

Comment: Yes, it's me.. I spend to much time here. I think that I have to concentrate on my studies, I just want to give my reputation to those for me I was most impressed. A sort of 'thank you for your intellect ;P'.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hover over the bounty mark:

[image]

You can also look at the [revision history of the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/457231/revisions).

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm sure I tried this but maybe without sufficient precision.